# Loop program if user enters wrong input

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0

I just started learning C# and while loops are confusing me. Unlike Java, where I can use a while loop to loop a program if a user entered a invalid input, it's not acting the same way in C#.

```
using System;

namespace first {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi! What is your name");
            string userName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("oh! you are:" + userName);
            Console.WriteLine("let play a game");

            string answer="Y";
            while (answer == "Y") {
                Random random = new Random();
                int correntNumber = random.Next(1, 2);
                int guess = 0;

                Console.WriteLine("Guess a number");
                while (guess != correntNumber) {
                    string userGuess = Console.ReadLine();

                    //validate input method 1
                    try {
                        guess = int.Parse(userGuess);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid inout", e);
                    }

                    //validate input method 2
                    //if(!int.TryParse(userGuess, out guess)) {
                    //    Console.WriteLine("invalid input");
                    //}

                    if (guess != correntNumber) {
                        Console.WriteLine("try again!");
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Yes! corrector");
                Console.WriteLine("Play again?");

                //string answer;
                answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                if(answer == "Y") {
                    continue;
                } else if (answer == "N") {
                    Console.WriteLine("bye");
                    return;
                } else if (answer != "Y" || answer != "N") {
                    Console.WriteLine("y or n");
                    answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter a value other than y or n, the message appears,Console.WriteLine("Y or n only");, but the game restarts while it shouldn't.

I am sorry this is a simple and rather silly question, but I can't pin point where I am going wrong.

Comment: @cigien, thank you for noticing that, I had changed but in my last edit, I didn't notice i had it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after printing to the user "y or n only" message, you take the input but you don't actually do anything with it
so the loop just restarts regardless of the input. To fix this issue, you could replace the last if part with this code

```
while(answer != 'Y' && answer != 'N'){
                    Console.WriteLine("y or n only");
                    answer = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                }
                 if(answer == 'Y')
            {
                continue;

            }
            else if(answer == 'N')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("goodbye");
                return;
            }
```

So after you read the first input answer of him for repeating, or no you check if it's a valid input or not, and if it's not, you keep asking him for "y or n only" till he enters "Y" or "N" and then you process this answer for whether it's a "Y" or "N" in the if part.

Comment: that was actually helpful! Thanks.